# Joining 2 shapes together in Illustrator. and removing a section while having rounded corners. Illustraor newbie

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

[image: Illustrator image]

How do I join these 2 shapes together, and then remove the line in the roof? keeping the 2 shapes nicely joined so I can easily round corners. Seems very tricky!

Comment: How are the corners rounded currently? Is it a stroke? Are they shapes?

Comment: Or, simply use the "divide" option in the pathfinder palette and it will create all as paths and then select the section you want to delete with the direct select (white) arrow.

Answer (score 5):

It's an extremely simple shape. Why not just draw two rectangles and a triangle, arrange them accordingly and assign them a stroke with “rounded joints”.

[image: Before]

Then select them all and use Pathfinder's “Add” operation.

[image: After]

That's it! This way, you can easily adjust the stroke thickness as required:

[image: After – alternative]

Answer (score 3):

If the path is just a stroke, you merely need to delete a section and add the new section making certain the anchors are connected. Stroke rounding will be retained.

[image]